# Is it possible to provide content editor ability to create sortable table?

Tags: nodes, theming

I know how to create a sortable table using

```
theme('table', $headers, $rows)
```

but is it possible to create a functionality so that a content creator can create a sortable table inside a content.
For example creating a sortable table inside a node.

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: I guess you should look for a javascript solution

Comment: Data will be entered by user while creating a node.

Comment: Is there any javascript solution provided by drupal ? I mean something that I can use from existing code base or should I consider using 3rd party library ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any Drupal module that will do what you're looking for. Take a look at this library http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo is this what your looking for?

Comment: What's the content of the table?

Comment: I have resolved this issue by creating a custom module using tablesorter javascript library.

Comment: @Randell Content of table are alphabets and numbers in form of HTML.

Comment: @user11, it's kinda hard to visualize it with just "alphabets and numbers in form of HTML". Would you be able to provide more info? I'm asking this because there could possibly be other ways of inputting the data instead of doing in within a the rich text editor. E.g. Entity reference of a content type acting like a node, containing another content type acting like rows.

Comment: @Randell I want to have a feature in content editor so that user can create a sortable data table. Table data will be in form of text, table data is not a separate entity.

Comment: Please do not edit answers directly into question. If you want me to delete my answer so you could post yours without double content issue, I can, no problem, just tell. Would be fair as it seems you solved it similar way in comments before I posted. But keep question part for question only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TableField](https://drupal.org/project/tablefield) module to create table that is a real html table. Sorting is currently unsupported, sadly, although [it would be wonderful](https://drupal.org/node/1491584).

If all you need is sorting on display, you can create a patch or your own module, and implement one of the jQuery plugins for sorting. Personally I found [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to work pretty OK.

Comment: A patch to add tablesorter to the display options via Libraries would be pretty easy.  Probably an hour or two.  Though if the output is run through `theme_table()`, you would just need to wire up the $sort option.  That would also be fairly easy (I think).

Answer (score 0):

see [drupal_add_dragtable](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_tabledrag/7)()

> Assists in adding the tableDrag JavaScript behavior to a themed table.
>
> Draggable tables should be used wherever an outline or list of
>   sortable items needs to be arranged by an end-user. Draggable tables
>   are very flexible and can manipulate the value of form elements placed
>   within individual columns.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by creating a custom module using tablesorter javascript library.